# In Spring Boot and Spring Security, can I get the time when I enter a specific page and how long I stay when the page exits?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-security

We are currently working on an LMS project. I want to create a lecture that I took a class at a certain time and took if it was more than the input time when I opened the class.

By the way, should I use a session or a thread to create something that time passes when I enter a specific page?

Anyone can give me directions

Comment: your description is not clear. But according to your question, I guess you need to assign certain expiration time to your sessions. If that is not what you want please edit your explanation to make it clearer.